# JUnit: can't find assertThat() method

Tags: java, spring, junit

Currently, I'm building a Spring Application and I want to write some tests using JUnit, but for some reason, the method assertThat() is not found by IntelliJ. Here is my code:

```
package com.mycompany;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import com.mycompany.book.Book;
import com.mycompany.book.BookRepository;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.Rollback;

@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase (replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@Rollback(value = false)
public class BookRepositoryTests {
    @Autowired private BookRepository repo;

    @Test
    public void testAddNew(){
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setTitle("The Divine Comedy");
        book.setAuthor("Dante Alighieri");
        book.setGenre("Poetry");

        Book savedBook = repo.save(book);

    }
}
```

I've tried to add manually the dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and I've also made sure to import it using:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using JUnit 5, so you shouldn't mix JUnit 4 into it just to get `assertThat`. That's part of a separate dependency, Hamcrest. JUnit 4 has a dependency on Hamcrest, but for JUnit 5 that integration has been removed. Instead, just include Hamcrest yourself (instead of JUnit 4):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```